# Dart preview Flutter UI guides is not present in vscode?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I can't find the dart preview flutter UI Guides... I have installed flutter and dart extensions in vscode... Can anyone help??

my Flutter version 2.10.4 and Dart version 2.16.2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot it looks like you're using an old version of VS Code (and that likely means an old version of the Dart/Flutter extensions). Try upgrading VS Code and then the Dart/Flutter extensions. The settings editor looks very different in the current VS Code version:

[image: VS Code Settings]